# Java Stream: Grouping and counting by multiple fields

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following object:

```
class Event {
private LocalDateTime when;
private String what;

public Event(LocalDateTime when, String what) {
  super();
  this.when = when;
  this.what = what;
}

public LocalDateTime getWhen() {
  return when;
}

public void setWhen(LocalDateTime when) {
  this.when = when;
}

public String getWhat() {
  return what;
}

public void setWhat(String what) {
  this.what = what;
}
```

}

I need to aggregate by year/month (yyyy-mm) and event type, and then count. For example the following list

```
List<Event> events = Arrays.asList(
  new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-03-03T09:01:16.111"), "EVENT1"),
  new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-03-03T09:02:11.222"), "EVENT1"),
  new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-03T09:04:11.333"), "EVENT1"), 
  new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-03T09:04:11.333"), "EVENT2"),
  new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-03T09:06:16.444"), "EVENT2"),
  new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-05-03T09:01:26.555"), "EVENT3")
);
```

should produce the following result:

```
Year/Month  Type  Count
2017-03     EVENT1    2  
2017-04     EVENT1    1
2017-04     EVENT2    2
2017-04     EVENT3    1
```

Any idea if (and if so, how) I can achieve that with Streams API?

Comment: you say that you want to aggregate by month, but the result also contains the year. So is it by month *and* year; or aggregate by month but show the year also?

Comment: I meant aggregate by year/month (yyyy-mm). I've edited the post :)

Comment: then any of the answers here qualify :)

Answer (score 8):

In case you don't want to create a new key class, as suggested by assylias, you can do a double `groupingBy`

```
Map<YearMonth,Map<String,Long>> map = 
     events.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> YearMonth.from(e.getWhen()),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getWhat(), Collectors.counting()))
                   );
```

... followed by a nested print

```
map.forEach((k,v)-> v.forEach((a,b)-> System.out.println(k + " " +  a + " " + b)));
```

This prints

```
2017-05 EVENT3 1
2017-04 EVENT2 2
2017-04 EVENT1 1
2017-03 EVENT1 2
```

---

EDIT: I noticed the order of the dates was the opposite of the OP's expected solution. Using the 3-parameter version of `groupingBy` you can specify a sorted map implementation

```
Map<YearMonth,Map<String,Long>> map = 
     events.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> YearMonth.from(e.getWhen()), TreeMap::new, 
                    Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getWhat(), Collectors.counting()))
                   );
```

The same `map.forEach(...)` now prints

```
2017-03 EVENT1 2
2017-04 EVENT2 2
2017-04 EVENT1 1
2017-05 EVENT3 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a "key" class that contains the year/month and the event type:

```
class Group {
  private YearMonth ym;
  private String type;

  public Group(Event e) {
    this.ym = YearMonth.from(e.getWhen());
    this.type = e.getWhat();
  }

  //equals, hashCode, toString etc.
}
```

You can then use that key to group your events:

```
Map<Group, Long> result = events.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Group::new, Collectors.counting()));
result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "\t" + v));
```

which outputs:

```
2017-04 EVENT1  1
2017-03 EVENT1  2
2017-04 EVENT2  2
2017-05 EVENT3  1
```

Comment: I like this solution, it seems the most OO to me. I would add a comment regarding ordering, i.e. implement `compareTo` in `Group` and using a `TreeMap`, or a `TreeMap` with a custom comparator.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to define your own key, you could `groupBy` twice. The result is the same, but in slightly different format:

```
 System.out.println(events.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> YearMonth.from(e.getWhen()),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getWhat, Collectors.counting()))));
```

And the result is:

```
 {2017-05={EVENT3=1}, 2017-04={EVENT2=2, EVENT1=1}, 2017-03={EVENT1=2}}
```

Comment: Grouping by `getMonth` will not take the year into account, the other answers use YearMonth for that purpose.

Comment: @MalteHartwig Yes I know, but the OP said: *I need to aggregate by month and event type*. It could easily be changed to year also...

Answer (score 0):

```
final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM");
    Stream.of(
            new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-03-03T09:01:16.111"), "EVENT1"),
            new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-03-03T09:02:11.222"), "EVENT1"),
            new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-03T09:04:11.333"), "EVENT1"),
            new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-03T09:04:11.333"), "EVENT2"),
            new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-03T09:06:16.444"), "EVENT2"),
            new Event(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-05-03T09:01:26.555"), "EVENT3")
            ).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(event -> 
               dateTimeFormatter.format(event.getWhen()),
               Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getWhat, counting())))
             .forEach((whenDate,v) -> v.forEach((whatKey,counter) -> 
                System.out.println(whenDate+ " "+ whatKey+" "+counter)));
```

No need to use an Arrays.asList() method to get to a stream. Use Stream.of() method directly to get a stream.

**Output**:

```
2017-03 EVENT1 2
2017-04 EVENT2 2
2017-04 EVENT1 1
2017-05 EVENT3 1
```

Comment: The OP gave a List in his example. Why wouldn't you want to use it? Besides that your answer is the same as mine.

Comment: Why would you use the Arrays class' static method to create a list and then transform that list to a stream when you can get a stream directly? I didn't look at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can create method in POJO has that contains list of fields to use for grouping by, like below

```
public String getWhenAndWhat() {
    return YearMonth.from(when) + ":" + what; //you can use delimiters like ':','-',','
}
```

And the stream code,

```
System.out.println(events.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getWhenAndWhat, Collectors.counting())));
```

Output would be:

> {2017-05:EVENT3=1, 2017-04:EVENT1=1, 2017-04:EVENT2=2, 2017-03:EVENT1=2}